# argocd cluster add is failing with weird error "connection reset by peer"

Tags: devops, argocd, argo, gitops

argocd cluster add is failing with weird error:

> time="2023-10-11T11:51:18-04:00" level=info msg="ServiceAccount
> "argocd-manager" already exists in namespace "kube-system""
> time="2023-10-11T11:51:18-04:00" level=info msg="ClusterRole
> "argocd-manager-role" updated" time="2023-10-11T11:51:18-04:00"
> level=info msg="ClusterRoleBinding "argocd-manager-role-binding"
> updated" time="2023-10-11T11:51:19-04:00" level=fatal msg="rpc error:
> code = Unknown desc = read: connection reset by peer"

I have never seen this error until today and its a new cluster setup I am trying to do. This issue is happening from one cluster and the second cluster is fine (no issues).
Any clue what might be the cause here?